# Can't echo after certain line

Tags: php, echo

I have some strange behaviour in my php script. For some reason, I can't create an echo, after a certain line.

```
include 'class/core.class.php';
include 'class/tp.class.php';

$tps = new tps;
$system = $_GET['system'];

$file = @fopen(getcwd() . "/csv/" . $system . ".csv", "r");
if(!$file) {
    echo "No data in " . getcwd() . "/csv";
    exit;
}

$tps->dropSystemData($system);

$counter = 0;

$data = array();

while($csv = fgetcsv($file, 0, ";")) {
    $data[$counter]['date'] = $csv[0];
    $data[$counter]['time'] = $csv[1];
    $data[$counter]['tp'] = $csv[2];

    $counter++;
}

foreach($data as $row) {
    $date = explode(".", $row['date']);
    echo 1; // Works
    $date = $date[2] . "/" . $date[1] . "/" . $date[0];
    echo 2; // Works
    $time = $row['time'];
    echo 3; // Works
    $tp = $row['tp'];
    echo 4; // Doesn't work
    echo $tp; // Doesn't work
    var_dump($tp); // Doesn't work
    var_dump($data); // This doesn't output anything like the echos and var_dumps before
}
```

I don't see any particular reason, why this shouldn't work. No errors at all.

Var_dump of `$data`

```
array(445) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "03.01.2012"
    ["time"]=>
    string(8) "12:30:06"
    ["tp"]=>
    string(10) "EN1K945540"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "04.01.2012"
    ["time"]=>
    string(8) "12:30:07"
    ["tp"]=>
    string(10) "EN1K945588"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "04.01.2012"
    ["time"]=>
    string(8) "12:30:09"
    ["tp"]=>
    string(10) "EN1K945592"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(3) {
    ["date"]=>
    string(10) "04.01.2012"
    ["time"]=>
    string(8) "12:30:09"
    ["tp"]=>
    string(10) "EN1K945594"
  }
```

Added the following to the beginning, but no errors or warnings:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
```

Update: I've changed the variable names now, but it still doesn't work.

Update 2: My bad, some caching issue, now closed and opened browser, now it's working. The duplicate variable names caused the problems.

Comment: show us `var_dump($row);`. i guess you don't have `['tp']` there

Comment: Have you got error reporting switched on? What does your PHP error log say?

Comment: Can you output `data` array, please ?

Comment: @konsolenfreddy Even with error reporting off, undefined indices are a notice and would not stop the rest of the script from echo'ing... That said, it's good to check because you never know.

Comment: check the php error logs & also show us some output

Comment: Updated question, now added a var_dump. Going to look at errors now.

Comment: What is $tp? You initialize it and then reset it to a string...

Comment: $tp is the class, but now as you said it, I changed the variables (it was not intended to overwrite it).

Comment: @Ahatius : where did you changed it? I don't see that

Comment: @DonCallisto Updated code, have a look at it.

Comment: Problem solved, DonCallisto's approach was right. Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do `$tp = new tp;` and assing to `$tp` an instance of `tp` Class

Into the cycle, instead, you assign it a `String` and that mess all the things up

Comment: Thanks, your solution solved it. Had to clear the cache, but i worked now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you in a browser? Does your $row['tp']; contain invalid HTML code or an angular brace? They may be interpreted as HTML tags and therefore no code may be shown. Check in the HTML/source...

Comment: Yes, I do test it in a browser, but the target isn't actually outputting the data (it should be inserted in to a db), but not beeing able to echo or var_dump makes debugging tricky, since I have some problems with the date string format.

Comment: My suggestion was to look at the raw HTML output, not at the browser rendering.

Comment: Oh, that's what I always do, I never look at the rendered output. Unfortunately the source was empty also.